# Code pipeline fails in source stage from github

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

My AWS CodePipeline role has s3 full access role. I have configured CodePipeline to download code from GitHub, But it fails in source stage with error:

The provided role does not have permissions to perform this action. Underlying error:

> Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
>   AccessDenied; Request ID: BDA77A60ED10A069; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   nQzv6LKkjAXeL0NjcgysjVj64G/7fVjvkidRS4IYjZrikJa+H1PUBdJXTmu4UD5N2x9zyAJGCdE=)

Comment: Double check the bucket policy

Comment: Any resolution to this? @Everton - Could you elaborate on what should be looked for in the bucket Policy? I'm getting the same error, but have 4 successful pipelines - just started getting this error when I set up a new pipeline.